# php get last year range date

Tags: php, datetime

I have a user in a database with a creation_date. This user can run a job in my app UI, but he is limited by a number of job to run in one year.

This user has been created in 2014. I would like to do something like :

```
function runJob($user){
    $nbRemainingJob = findReminingJobs($user);
    if ($nbRemainingJob > 0){ 
         runJob($user);
    }
    else {
         die("no more credits";)
    }
}
findReminingJobs($user){
      $dateRangeStart = ?; //start date to use
      $endRangeStart = ?; //end date to use
      $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM jobs WHERE user_id=?";
      $sql .= "AND job_created_at BETWEEN ($dateRangeStart AND $endRangeStart)";
      $res = $pdo->execute($sql, [$user->id]);
      $done = $res->fetchOne();
      return ($user->max_jobs - $done);

}
```

Every user's creation birthday, the $user->max_jobs is reset.

The question is how to find starting/ending date ? in other words, I would like to get a range of date starting from the user's creation date.
For example, if the user was created on 2014-04-12, my start_date should be 2018-04-12 and my end_date = 2019-04-11.

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't get the logic you want to apply. So if the user was created in 2014-01-12, why the start date should be 2018-04-12?

Comment: @pr1nc3 because, the number of jobs is valid for 1 year. So I have to define what is the last year starting from day & month of the user's creation. It means every user's creation birthday, the max_jobs is reset

Comment: I got that but if the user was created on  2014-01-12 shouldn't start date be 2018-01-12 and end_date be 2019-01-11?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. It was a mistake. I updated the post

Comment: Also what happens if the user created on 2025-04-12? the start date will be the current date right?

Comment: What is the `$user`? An object? Does it have access its creation day?

Comment: Yes the $user variable represente the User object with it's creation_date

Answer (score 0):

First get the user register date from db and split it into Year, Month and Day like

```
$register= explode('-', $userCridate);
$month = $register[0];
$day   = $register[1];
$year  = $register[2];
```

Then get the current year like

```
$year = date("Y");
$dateRangeStart = $year."-".$month."-".$day; //start date to use
```

Now, check if this date is greater then today date, then use last year as starting date

```
$previousyear = $year -1;
$dateRangeStart = $previousyear ."-".$month."-".$day; //start date to use

$endRangeStart = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateRangeStart)) 
. " + 365 day"));
```

It is a idea, check if it work for you.

Comment: this method don't work. the problem is that the starting date is 2014-04-12, if I use your method, it will give me 2015-04-11 which is not the expected result. the difficulty is to get the right starting date

Comment: it's not that simple. again the complexity is to define the starting date, and you can't do it your way. It depends on if the month/day are greater, smaller or equal than the current date. but I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$created='2025-04-12';
$date=explode('-',$created);


if($date[0]<date("Y")){
    $newDate=date('Y').'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[2];
    $dateEnding = strtotime($newDate);
    $dateEnding = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 year",$dateEnding));
}
else{
    $newDate=$created;
    $dateEnding = strtotime($newDate);
    $dateEnding = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 year",$dateEnding));
}


echo 'starting date is: '.$newDate;
echo '</br>';
echo 'ending date is: '.$dateEnding;
```

This code will get the date you have and match it with the current year. If the year of the date you provided is equal or above the current year the start date will be your date and end date will be current date +1 year. Otherwise if the year is below our current year (2014) it will replace it with the current year and add 1 year for the end date. Some example outputs:

For input

```
$created='2014-04-12';
```

The output is :

```
starting date is: 2018-04-12
ending date is: 2019-04-12
```

But for input

```
$created='2025-04-12';
```

The outpus is :

```
starting date is: 2025-04-12
ending date is: 2026-04-12
```

Comment: @pr1inc3, thanks for you answer I had this approach in mind but tougth there is something built in that do the stuff.

Comment: I don't think so. It's your algorithm so you must apply the logic to it. Php has build in functions to help you do it  but there is no silver bullet for issues like this. I hope i helped you a bit to solve your issue.

Comment: An issue with your code, if creation_date is 2014-09-13, this gives me : start_date=2014-09-13, end_date=2016-09-12

Comment: I gave the date you said and the output is correct : starting date is: 2018-09-13
ending date is: 2019-09-13

I think you missed something

Comment: I can't count jobs run after 2018-09-13 because the date is in the futur. I adapted your code to match the need, I'll post it here

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRange($registrationDate) {
    $range = array();

    // Split registration date components
    list($registrationYear, $registrationMonth, $registrationDay) = explode('-', $registrationDate);
    // Define range start year
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $startYear = $registrationYear < $currentYear ? $currentYear :     $registrationYear;
    // Define range boudaries
    $range['start'] = "$startYear-$registrationMonth-$registrationDay";
    $range['end'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($range['start'] . ' + 364 day'));

    return $range;
}
```

And for your example:

```
print_r(getRange('2014-04-12'));

Array
(
    [start] => 2018-04-12
    [end] => 2019-04-11
)

print_r(getRange('2014-09-13'));

Array
(
    [start] => 2018-09-13
    [end] => 2019-09-12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that match my need :

```
$now = new DateTime();

    $created_user = date_create($created);

    $diff = $now->diff($created_user)->format('%R%a');
    $diff = abs(intval($diff));
    $year = intval($diff / 365);

    if ($year == 0){
        $startDate=$created_user->format("Y-m-d");
    }else{

        $startDate=$created_user->add(new DateInterval("P".$year."Y"))->format("Y-m-d");
    }
```

The problem was to define the starting date that is comprised in the one year range max from the current date  and starting from the user's creation date.

So if the user's creation_date is older than one year, than I do +1 year, if not, take this date. the starting date must not be greater than the current date_time

thanks to all for your help